# Command substitution in shell script without globbing

Tags: shell, posix

Consider this little shell script.

```
# Save the first command line argument
cmd="$1"

# Execute the command specified in the first command line argument
out=$($cmd)

# Do something with the output of the specified command
# Here we do a silly thing, like make the output all uppercase
echo "$out" | tr -s "a-z" "A-Z"
```

The script executes the command specified as the first argument, transforms the output obtained from that command and prints it to standard output. This script may be executed in this manner.

```
sh foo.sh "echo select * from table"
```

This does not do what I want. It may print something like the following,

```
$ sh foo.sh "echo select * from table"
SELECT FILEA FILEB FILEC FROM TABLE
```

if fileA, fileB and fileC is present in the current directory.

From a user perspective, this command is reasonable. The user has quoted the `*` in the command line argument, so the user doesn't expect the `*` to be globbed. But my script astonishes the user by using this argument in a command substitution which causes globbing of `*` as seen in the above output.

I want the output to be the following instead.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

The entire text in `cmd` actually comes from command line arguments to the script so I would like to preserve any `*` symbol present in the argument without globbing them.

I am looking for a solution that works for any POSIX shell.

One solution I have come up with is to disable globbing with `set -o noglob` just before the command substitution. Here is the complete code.

```
# Save the first command line argument
cmd="$1"

# Execute the command specified in the first command line argument
set -o noglob
out=$($cmd)

# Do something with the output of the specified command
# Here we do a silly thing, like make the output all uppercase
echo "$out" | tr -s "a-z" "A-Z"
```

This does what I expect.

```
$ sh foo.sh "echo select * from table"
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

Apart from this, is there any other concept or trick (such as a quoting mechanism) I need to be aware of to disable globbing only within a command substitution without having to use `set -o noglob`.

I am not against `set -o noglob`. I just want to know if there is another way. You know, globbing can be disabled for normal command line arguments just by quoting them, so I was wondering if there is anything similar for command substiution.

Comment: Do you mean you want the output to be `select * from table`? Your question currently states that your desired output is identical to your actual output (`select fileA fileB fileC from table`).

Comment: @bgoldst You are right. I have fixed it in my question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the user to provide a *shell command* as a command-line argument, which will be executed by the script, and is expected to produce an SQL string, which will be processed (upper-cased) and echoed to stdout.

The first thing to say is that there is no point in having the user provide a shell command that the script just blindly executes. If the script applied some kind of modification/preprocessing of the command before it executed it then perhaps it could make sense, but if not, then the user might as well execute the command himself and pass the output to the script as a command-line argument, or via stdin.

But that being said, if you really want to do it this way, then there are two things that need to be said. Firstly, this is the proper form to use:

```
out=$(eval "$cmd");
```

A fairly advanced understanding of the shell grammer and expansion rules would be required to fully understand the rationale for using the above syntax, but basically executing `$cmd` and executing `eval "$cmd"` have subtle differences that render the `$cmd` form inappropriate for executing a given shell command string.

Just to give some detail that will hopefully clarify the above point, there are seven kinds of *expansion* that are performed by the shell in the following order when processing input: (1) brace expansion, (2) tilde expansion, (3) parameter and variable expansion, (4) arithmetic expansion, (5) command substitution, (6) word splitting, and (7) pathname expansion. Notice that *variable expansion* happens somewhat in the middle of that sequence, and thus the variable-expanded shell command (which was provided by the user) will not receive the benefit of the prior expansion types. Other issues are that leading variable assignments, pipelines, and command list tokens will not be executed correctly under the `$cmd` form, because they are parsed and processed prior to variable expansion (actually prior to *all* expansions) as well.

By running the command through `eval`, properly double-quoted, you ensure that the full shell parsing/processing/execution algorithm will be applied to the shell command string that was given by the user of your script.

The second thing to say is this: If you try the above proper form in your script, you will find that it has *not* solved your problem. You will still get `SELECT FILEA FILEB FILEC FROM TABLE` as output.

The reason is this: Since you've decided you want to accept an arbitrary shell command from the user of your script, it is now the *user's* responsibility to properly quote all metacharacters that may be embedded in that piece of code. It does not make sense for you to accept a shell command as a command-line argument, but somehow change the processing rules for shell commands so that certain metacharacters will no longer be metacharacters when the given shell command is executed. Actually, you *could* do something like that, perhaps using `set -o noglob` as you discovered, but then that must become a contract between the script and the user of the script; the user must be made aware of exactly what the precise processing rules will be when the command is executed so that he can properly use the script.

Under this design, the user could call the script as follows (notice the extra layer of quoting for the shell command string evaluation; could alternatively backslash-escape just the asterisk):

```
$ sh foo.sh "echo 'select * from table'";
```

I'd like to return to my earlier comment about the overall design; it doesn't really make sense to do it this way. It makes more sense to take the text-to-process itself, *not* a shell command that is expected to produce the text-to-process.

Here is how that could be done:

```
## take the text-to-process via a command-line argument
sql="$1";

## process and echo it
echo "$sql"| tr a-z A-Z;
```

(I also removed the `-s` option of `tr`, which really doesn't make sense here.)

Notice that the script is simpler now, and usage is also simpler:

```
$ sh foo.sh 'select * from table';
```